# ffmpeg how to create list of input files and refer them in complex filter

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay

I have input video and long (1000s) list of png files.
I'd like to overlay pngs at different timestamps.
I created filter_complex_script like:

```
[0:v][1:v] overlay=enable='between(t, 0.05, 0.116)'[tmp];
[tmp][2:v] overlay=enable='between(t, 0.116, 0.283)'[tmp];
[tmp][3:v] overlay=enable='between(t, 0.283, 0.433)'[tmp].....
```

and this works as long as I manually pass file names in cmd line so

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -i ov1.png -i ov2.png -filter_complex_script f.txt test2.mp4
```

But I cannot use concat as input as I lost references to single files, so this doesn't wotk

```
ffmpeg  -f concat  -i files.txt -filter_complex_script f.txt test2.mp4
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: you could try to create script which gets all filenames and generate string like `ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -i ov1.png -i ov2.png ...`  and save in `script.sh` and then you can run `script.sh`. But it will create very long command and I don't know if system may get soo long command.

Comment: this is how I use this now, but it's very limited

Comment: normally I would use Python (or any other script language) to make it simpler. If all files are in one folder and all have names `ov1.png`, `ov2.png`, etc. then script language could read all names in folder and generate `ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -i ov1.png -i ov2.png ...` and save in `script.sh` or directly execute it. With Python maybe I would use even module [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python)

Comment: None of solution solve problem with max length of command line, I have thousands of files

Comment: @pma_ try using `xargs` to run the command in batches and avoid any 'argument list too long' bash errors.

Comment: See [Is it possible to provide input files list to FFmpeg in a text file instead of on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64407313/1670156).  However, if you are trying to do what I think you are trying to do, which is to generate a variable frame-rate video overlay, then see instead: [FFmpeg: Is it possible to replace frames in a variable frame-rate video?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63880205/1670156)